# Limit number of eager loaded objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there a way to limit the number of eager loaded objects through associations?

Consider the following example:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apples      
end

class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

I want to get all of the people, loading their apples...

```
Person.includes(:apples).limit(10)
```

...but I want to limit the number of `apple` objects loaded per person to 5, this loads **all** `apples`.

I have tried the following:

1. Define a new relation on the Person model

   ```
   class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :apples
     has_many :limited_apples, class_name: 'Apple', limit: 5
   end
   ```
2. Use `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader`

   ```
   people = Person.limit(50)
   ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(people, :limited_apples, limit: 5).run
   ```

Both approaches fail to limit the number of objects loaded through the `:apples` association. Am I leading myself down a rabbit hole, or missing something blatantly obvious?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this is not possible.

> If you eager load an association with a specified :limit option, it will be ignored, returning all the associated objects. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much came to that conclusion. Thanks though :)